# Flow.CurrentDate returns System date or User date

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-flow

Flow.CurrentDate returns whether System date or User date?
Is it similar to System.today()?

I am Expecting Flow.CurrentDate returns User date, but i am worried whether it will return user date or System date. Please confirm

Answer (score 0):

It returns the user date!

I had the same question so I just tested id by using a flow pushing the current date into a random date field on the account. I changed my timezone and used it again and the result was different.